# After installing/upgrading to Kentico 8.1, why are certain built-in files excluded from the project?

Tags: project, solution, kentico, build-script

The Kentico 8.1 installer plops out the proprietary Kentico solution structure with its 11,700+ files and 1,900+ folders, and three .csproj projects whose files overlap in the same directory structure.  I noticed that a few files aren't included in any of those three projects:

- \App_Themes\Default\Bootstrap\close.less
- \App_Themes\Default\CMSComponents\mass-actions.less
- \CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\plugins\CMSPlugins\images\InsertImageAttachment.png
- \CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\plugins\enterkey\samples\enterkey.html
- \CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\plugins\htmlwriter\samples\assets\outputforflash.html
- \CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\plugins\htmlwriter\samples\assets\outputforhtml.html
- \CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\plugins\htmlwriter\samples\assets\outputforflash\outputforflash.fla
- \CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\plugins\htmlwriter\samples\assets\outputforflash\outputforflash.swf
- \CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\plugins\htmlwriter\samples\assets\outputforflash\swfobject.js
- \CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\plugins\sharedspace\samples\sharedspace.html
- \CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\plugins\sourcedialog\samples\sourcedialog.html
- \CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\plugins\toolbar\samples\toolbar.html
- \CMSAdminControls\CKeditor\plugins\wysiwygarea\samples\fullpage.html
- \CMSModules\Content\Controls\MassActions.ascx.designer.cs
- \CMSResources\CMS.cs-cz.resx
- \CMSResources\CMS.sk-sk.resx
- \CMSScripts\Vendor\jQuery\jquery-1.11.0-amd.js
- \Old_App_Code\CMSModules\OnlineMarketing\OnlineMarketingLoader.cs

Which of these should be added to the project?  Which should be omitted?  Which can be deleted?

Comment: I got a reply from a Kentico developer on Kentico's own forums about OnlineMarketingLoader.cs: "The file is not important and will be removed in the future versions. Do not add it into the project."

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe to remove all mentioned files, here are some remarks:

- *.less - you need only the generated *.css files
- ckeditor\plugins* - seem to be leftovers after upgrading CK editor. they don't seem to be referenced anywhere
- MassActions.ascx.designer.cs - not used anymore
- CMSResources* - localization files can be installed later using Kentico Installer if needed
- jquery-1.11.0-amd.js - don't think it is used
- OnlineMarketingLoader.cs - will be removed as you wrote in your comment

However, there is no reason to delete the files at all.